How to get assembly to properly read a write contents from a file?
I been trying for the past few days to calculate e^x and e^-x using the taylor expansion of e, where x is the values read from a file. But I've been stuck trying to get it to actually print numbers, because it prints the variables string properly, but when it goes to print the values, the program doesn't run anything and typing causes garbage to appear until I press Contol-C to end it.
As for what I've tried...

Initially, the calculation algorithim wasn't in its own subroutine, when it was like this, it would properly print out x = 0, but segmentation fault for the next one.

I moved the printf call for printing the values to after the exp_calc function call
-Adding a null character to the variable string.

I also tried loading them into register I never used
-I used gdb to try and figure things out, but the it just prints the 'infinite loop?' without really telling me where and whats wrong.


But nothing I tried changed anything, so I have no clue what's going on here.
Here is the code:
.data
limit:  .double 0r1.0e-13        // Limit for convergence

.text
variables: .string "     x       |     e^x       |     e^(-x)       |\n"
values:    .string "     %0.10f  |     %0.10f    |     %0.10f       |\n"
errors:    .string "ERROR! File not found!\n"

buffer = 8                       // Buffer size for reading from file
alloc = -(16 + buffer) & -16     // Allocate space on the stack
dealloc = -alloc
buffer_s = 16                    // Buffer size for storing input value

// Register aliases
define(argc, w20)
define(argv, x21)
define(buff, x22)
define(nread, x23)
define(fd, w24)

        .balign 4
        .global main
main:   stp     x29, x30, [sp, alloc]!  // Save frame pointer and link register
        mov     x29, sp                 // Set up new frame pointer

        mov     argc, w0                // argc (number of arguments)
        mov     argv, x1                // argv (argument values)

        cmp     argc, 1                 // Check if no file name is provided
        b.le    error                   // Branch to error if argc <= 1

        mov     w0, -100
        ldr     x1, [x1, buffer]    // Load file name from argv

        mov     w2, 0                   // Open file for reading
        mov     w3, 0
        mov     x8, 56
        svc     0
        mov     fd, w0                  // File descriptor
        cmp     fd, 0
        b.lt    error                   // Branch to error if file open failed

        // File open succeeded
        adrp    x0, variables
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:variables
        bl      printf                  // Print column headers

        add     buff, x29, buffer_s     // Buffer for storing input value

loop:
        mov     w0, fd                // File descriptor
        mov     x1, buff
        mov     w2, 8                   // Read 8 bytes (double precision)
        mov     x8, 63
        svc     0
        mov     nread, x0               // Number of bytes read
        cmp     nread, 8                // Check for end of file
        b.ne    end                     // Branch to end if end of file

        ldr     d0, [buff]              // Load input value
        bl      exp_calc
        fmov    d1, d7

        ldr     d0, [buff]              // Load input value
        fneg    d0, d0
        bl      exp_calc
        fmov    d2, d7

        adrp    x0, values
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:values
        bl      printf                  // Print x, e^x, and e^(-x)

        b       loop                    // Process next input value

exp_calc:
        fmov    d2, d0                  // x
        ldr     d1, [sp, limit]         // Load limit
        bl      exp_series              // Calculate e^x
        fmov    d0, d4                  // Store e^x in d0
        bl      exp_series              // Calculate e^(-x)
        fmov    d1, d4                  // Store e^(-x) in d1
        ret                             // Return to caller

exp_series:
        fmov    d4, 1.0                 // Initialize e^x
        mov     x4, 0                   // Initialize term counter
        fmov    d5, 1.0                 // Initialize factorial
        fmov    d6, d0                  // Initialize x^n
        fmov    d11, 1.0

exp_loop:
        fmul    d6, d6, d0              // x^(n+1)
        fadd    d5, d5, d11             // (n+1)!
        fdiv    d7, d6, d5              // x^(n+1)/(n+1)!
        fadd    d4, d4, d7              // e^x += term
        fabs    d7, d7                  // Absolute value of term
        fcmp    d7, d1                  // Check if term is less than limit
        b.gt    exp_loop                // Continue loop if term is greater than limit

        ret                             // Return to caller

error:
        adrp    x0, errors
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:errors
        bl      printf                  // Print error message

end:
        mov     w0, fd                // File descriptor
        mov     x8, 57                  // close I/O request
        svc     0                       // call system function
        mov     w0, 0                 // return 0

        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], dealloc // Restore frame pointer and link register
        ret                             // Return to caller


add buff, x29, buffer_s makes no sense and buff is not allocated anywhere. Also if you are using printf why are you using raw svc calls for file i/o?

@Jester: buff is defined as an alias for x22.
